# Swift - Hiding the local notification dismiss button

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I have a small reminder app that relies on the user successfully clicking one of my custom actions on the local notification. If the user mistakenly taps the  'dismiss' button (please see screen shot below) the notification disappears and my app doesn't know to do the next task.

Is there any way to remove this dismiss option from the local notification in Swift?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to include the image?

Comment: I apologize.. but I need more reputation to post images. Ugh

Comment: Opps.  Guess I didn't realize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible to remove the dismiss button. Also, your app logic shouldn't believe on Notification actions, since there is no guarantee on the following user actions:
- When receive a notification
- When dismiss a notification
- When expire or dont receive

What you can do it's allow the user to set a timer. After the notification is sent, if there are no interactions with in X seconds/minutes you send the notification again.

Comment: I totally agree on the app logic not relying on custom notification actions. That is kind of my problem. As I see it, IOS offers no way to run background actions outside of local notifications... so the app has no way of being notified when it's time to load up more data.  - The timer idea is interesting but I am not sure what you are referring to. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible. The documentation does not mention anything about the dismiss icon.

You can view the UIUserNotificationAction class reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIUserNotificationAction_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIUserNotificationAction/destructive).

Comment: I am aware of the developer documentation but thanks!